# [My]SQL Query Syntax which requires foreach processing

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I have an SQL query task which I can do OK in C# or linqpad but would prefer it is in SQL so standard reporting tools can do it.

End DB is a bugzilla under MySQL

> > The problem is I need to loop through the bug_activity looking for particular changes to consider the parent record "valid", how ?
> >     e.g. pseudo logic like

```
  if bug_status went to IN BACKLOG
  then bug_status went to ASSIGNED 
  and this happened 2016-03-01 to 206-03-31 
  then consider valid record
```

> > I am unsure how to do this as web examples only show DECLARE and LOOPs but how a loop fits into the "select, from, where" code.

```
set @BugID = 64252;

select
     bugs_activity.bug_id,
--   profiles.realname,
--   profiles.login_name,
     bugs_activity.bug_when,
     fielddefs.name, 
     bugs_activity.added
--   bugs_activity.removed
from
     bugs_activity,
     profiles,
     fielddefs

-- Real world 'Where xx' will have more logic and result in a number of bugzilla records 
-- Each bugzilla record has its own 'bugs_activity'
-- Logic needs to look at each buzilla records historyto filter results 
-- Want to end up with a filtered record set and a total number of records
Where  bug_id = @BugID AND bugs_activity.who = profiles.userid AND bugs_activity.fieldid = fielddefs.id
```

Example of bug_activity

```
bug_id bug_when name added
64252 26/01/2016 6:51:30 AM status_whiteboard ID:103138574 
64252 26/01/2016 6:52:10 AM cc xxx@abc.com 
64252 28/01/2016 9:49:10 AM bug_status IN BACKLOG 
64252 28/01/2016 9:49:10 AM cf_escalation_notes Effort: 2
Reproduced by support 
64252 28/01/2016 9:49:10 AM assigned_to def@abc.com 
64252 2/05/2016 4:33:05 PM bug_status ASSIGNED
```

Comment: Can you explain your requirements a bit more? You can probably do it without a loop. SQL is set based, looping defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  bug_id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN bug_status='IN BACKLOG' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as backlogCount,
  SUM(CASE WHEN bug_status='ASSIGNED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as assignedCount
FROM bugs_activity
WHERE action_date BETWEEN '2016-03-01' AND '206-03-31'
GROUP BY bug_id
HAVING backlogCount>0 AND assignedCount>0
```

The select returns bug_ids which were in 'IN BACKLOG' and in 'ASSIGNED' statuses during the period. You can use the query above in your FROM section instead of `bugs_activity`

UPDATE:

Add in the SELECT section

```
  MAX(CASE WHEN bug_status='IN BACKLOG' THEN action_date ELSE NULL END) as backlogDate,
  MAX(CASE WHEN bug_status='ASSIGNED' THEN action_date ELSE NULL END) as assignedDate
```

and then in HAVING section `AND backlogDate<assignedDate`

Comment: Thanks this gave me enough to get

Comment: Thanks this gave me enough to get 
`'SELECT 
  bug_id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN fielddefs.name ='bug_status' AND bugs_activity.added = 'IN BACKLOG' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as backlogCount,
  SUM(CASE WHEN fielddefs.name ='bug_status' AND bugs_activity.added = 'ASSIGNED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as assignedCount
FROM bugs_activity, fielddefs
WHERE bug_when BETWEEN '2016-03-01' AND '2016-03-31'
GROUP BY bug_id
HAVING backlogCount>0 AND assignedCount>0'`

How to I move the "WHERE Bug_when" logic into the Select - want StateA then StateB provided StateB inside date ? Thanks