# MySQL - How to Print our row count of matching table item

Tags: mysql, sql

In [[My]SQL Query Syntax which requires foreach processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37430135/mysql-query-syntax-which-requires-foreach-processing) I have an add on question which is standalone so I am asking in new post.

> > The SQL did find the info, however I would like to print the number of bug_activity rows with the id = bug_id ?

Each bug has a bug_activity table with a bug_id
I am not sure if I can print the pre vetted count which the SELECT and WHERE vet..

```
SELECT 
  bug_id,
  COUNT(*) as ActivityRecords, -- Want this to be the number of bugs_activity records with the id bug_id
  SUM(CASE WHEN fielddefs.name ='bug_status' AND (bugs_activity.added = 'IN BACKLOG' OR bugs_activity.added = 'ASSIGNED') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as OpenCount
FROM bugs_activity, fielddefs
WHERE bug_when BETWEEN '2016-03-01' AND '2016-03-31'
GROUP BY bug_id
HAVING OpenCount>0
```

Example of output

```
Result Set (43 items) 
bug_id OpenCount <= like to add total activity records for bug
43350 3 
62609 1 
63961 1
```

Comment: Can you clarify if it is mysql or tsql that you are dealing with? You can't tag both.

Comment: MySQL is the backend, using Linqpad SQL language in trial or can use MySQL Workbench if this is important.